# Fraction class: How can define a function to add a fraction to an integer?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I am learning the fraction class of Python and have a question below:

```
class Fraction:

     def __add__(self, other):
         newnum = self.num * other.den + self.den * other.num
         newden = self.den * other.den
         return Fraction(newnum, newden)

     def __radd__(self, other_int):
         newnum = self.num + self.den * other_int
         return Fraction(newnum, self.den)

x = Fraction(1, 2)
```

When I write this, I got the right answer (3/2):

```
print(1 + x)
```

But when I write this:

```
print(x + 1)
```

I got the error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'den'
```

Why `print(1 + x)` was correctly printed, `print(x + 1)` was error? How can I `print(x + 1)` get the answer 3/2.

Comment: Please format correctly and give us enough of the class to try this out (at least the constructor is missing).

Comment: You need to do OOP homework before asking questions.  google python oop.

Comment: Put 1 as `Fraction(1,1)` You can also specify in your class when self or other is of type int the convert it into Fraction object.

Comment: `other` is an `int` (`1`) and you've asked for `other.den`. `'int' object has no attribute 'den'`.

Comment: Forgive me, this is my first edit. I could have shown you all the code(it's a little long), thank you all the same.

Answer (score 3):

`x + 1` triggers `__add__` with `1` as the `other` argument:

```
class Fraction:
    def __add__(self, other):
        print(other)

Fraction() + 3  # prints 3
```

In your `__add__` you ask for `other.den`. Since `other` is `1`, this can't work.

Comment: so, if I want to add 1/2 to 1, how to define the function in the class Fraction?(I have made def __add__(self, other):newnum = self.num * other.den + self.den * other.num
  newden = self.den * other.den
  return Fraction(newnum, newden)), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your problem I think what you need to do is

```
>>> x = Fraction(1, 2)
>>> y = Fraction(1, 0)
```

then try

```
>>> x + y
>>> y + x
```

Both will work

To explain how it works will take an entire book.

Comment: can you tell us how and when the method __radd__ will get triggered

Comment: I am also learner like you. Thanks for teaching me.

Comment: @RajanChahan I am learning the book and want to solve the question 7, so, I have a question above: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Introduction/ProgrammingExercises.html

Comment: __radd__ is called when right side of argument doesn't support the __add__ something like that.

Comment: @Chris Here is a nice Reddit thread for you https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3cvgpi/can_someone_explain_radd_to_me_in_simple_terms_i/

Comment: @RajanChahan Thank you very much!